# Convert special characters to normal characters in Java

Tags: java

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert any odd characters to a basic aA-zZ style. For example, converting "нello тнєяє" to "Hello There". Is there anything for Java to convert any and all letter-like characters to their respective characters?

Comment: Define _odd_ and _special_, ie. the mapping.

Comment: Any character that is not "Latin Capital or Latin Small"

Comment: Now define _respective characters_.

Comment: The closest character that is "Latin Capital or Latin Small". I want to be able to convert a string into just basic characters for a chat filter

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _closest character_. This is a custom mapping that you seem to have defined yourself. You'll have to express it better.

Comment: Well, all of these characters are within ASCII and Unicode, I know there are a lot of characters, but is there any way to determine if the character was designed to look like a basic character, and if it is, replace it with it. For example, the character "ℳ", Unicode name "SCRIPT CAPITAL M", was intentionally designed to look like "M", but can't be checked for in a filter, unless explicitly replaced. Unless there is a better way.

Comment: _is there any way to determine if the character was designed to look like a basic character_ No, I don't think so. Right now, it seems like you'll need your own mapping.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is that there is no automatic mapping to convert Unicode symbols to Latin [A-Za-z] letters based on their *appearance*, because appearance is subjective and arbitrary.  If you want to do this you must decide for yourself how to map each character.  For starters, consider the  Greek letter 'eta' (Η or Unicode 0x0397).  Graphically it looks like the letter `H`, but semantically it's not.  Or, consider Cyrillic 'er' (Р or Unicode 0x0420) ... looks like `P` but represents `R`.

Venturing further afield, consider Thaana letter Gaafu, (ގ or Unicode 0x078E).  It seems somewhat meaningless to consider this a variant of the letter `S`.

I'm sure you can find *lots* of non-Latin symbols that vaguely resemble Latin characters but the answer to your question is that there is no existing mapping.  You would have to define it based on your own criteria for similarity.